# How to solve this confusing iterative limit equation

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

I have this equation which is intended to be used on a data set of integers. I am attempting to create a software algorithm using this equation, but I am very confused about how to implement it.

Things that confuse me about this equation:

- I am supposed to be getting a single value result from the equation, which confuses me because it seems to be some kind of iterative function. I.e. how to know what the first J value is, what to do with all the J values, etc..
- I am also confused by the limit being as Delta J approaches 0.
- Why is the limit wrapped inside a min function? Why would the limit return more than one value?
- Finally, why does this equation involve imaginary numbers and how do you deal with that?

$$
  \operatorname{Re}(J_{i+1}) = \min \left(\lim_{\Delta J\to 0} \left(\frac{\log({R}/{\sigma NJ_i})}{\log(1/N)}\right)\right)
$$

Where $R$ is the range of the data, $\sigma$ is the standard deviation, and $N$ is the number of values in data set. The purpose of the equation is to collect some kind of fractal data modeling statistic (don't know what this means) to use for machine learning purposes. The data set is comprised of 3-digit values that are taken from reading in binary file data.

Comment: Providing some more context would help us to help you. Where did this equation come from? Do you know what any of the symbols in the equation represent? Where does the data set of integers come from (what do they represent)?

Comment: Sorry, yes of course I will update the question.